# How to switch Property Name based on String Variable?

Tags: c#, linq

In the line code below, how to replace the FirstProperty based on the value of PropertyName?

```
 var PropertyName = "SecondProperty"; // propNames.Where(n => n ==anArgument).FirstOrDefault();
 var result = db.GetData().Where(i = i.FirstProperty.ToString().Contains(someString));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using reflection:

```
var PropertyName = "SecondProperty";
 var result = db.GetData().Where(i = i.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(i).ToString().Contains(someString));
```